# How to identify encoded format is base64 or not

Tags: base64, decode

I have a code that looks like a base64.  I used multiple decoders online but it retrieved blank,. Now I'm not sure if it's a base64.  This is the code cXdJM50PIEUBe31uLYIC/A==

Answer (score 0):

Its not a baase64 image, if its base 64 encoded image after paste the browser, display the image in browser check yourself,

```
src="data:image/png;base64,cXdJM50PIEUBe31uLYIC/A=="
```

paste only,

```
data:image/png;base64,cXdJM50PIEUBe31uLYIC/A==
```

Actual base64 image looks like this,

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```